# Changing my variable creates infinite loop

Tags: c#

I've been learning about Python lately, but recently wanted to do a project that involved a 2D array, so I decided to switch over to C# (So sorry if my code is poor)

Basically I'm writing a program that does a crossword puzzle for me.

- I have `i` iterating through top/bottom
- I have `j` iterating through left to right

I find the first letter `i` want - lets call this "keyletter"

Now I need to look in all 8 spaces around it. If the `i/j` position is `[1,2]`, I'm looking at `[0,2]` first.

In my code I want to change `i` from `1` to `0`, and print, (if this is the correct letter) second letter is: `[0,2]`

As soon as I change `i` from `1` to `0` and try to print, it spits it out a million times and gets stuck.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string keyLetter = "g";
    string keyLetter2 = "b";
    string[,] crossword = new string[,] 
    { 
        { "a", "b", "c", "d" },
        { "e", "f", "g", "h" }, 
        { "a", "e", "b", "c" }, 
        { "i", "j", "k", "l" }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < crossword.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < crossword.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (keyLetter == crossword[i, j])
            {
                Console.Write(keyLetter + " is [" + i + ", " + j + "]");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("i is: " + i);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("j is: " + j);
                Console.WriteLine();

                if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i - 1, j])
                {
                    // i--;
                    Console.Write("[i/j] position for " + keyLetter2 + " is [" + i + 
                        ", " + j + "]");
                }
                else if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i + 1, j])
                {
                    Console.Write("[i/j] position for " + keyLetter2 + " is [" + i + 
                        ", " + j + "]");
                }
                /*
                else if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i + 1, j - 1])
                {
                    Console.Write("[i/j] position for " + keyLetter2 + " is [" + i + 
                        ", " + j + "]");
                }
                else if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i, j - 1])
                {
                    Console.Write("[i/j] position for " + keyLetter2 + " is [" + i + 
                        ", " + j + "]");
                }
                else if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i - 1, j - 1])
                {
                    Console.Write("[i/j] position for " + keyLetter2 + " is [" + i + 
                        ", " + j + "]");
                }
                else if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i + 1, j + 1])
                {
                    Console.Write("[i/j] position for " + keyLetter2 + " is [" + i + 
                        ", " + j + "]");
                }
                else if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i, j + 1])
                {
                    Console.Write("[i/j] position for " + keyLetter2 + " is [" + i + 
                        ", " + j + "]");
                }
                else if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i - 1, j + 1])
                {
                    Console.Write("[i/j] position for " + keyLetter2 + " is [" + i + 
                        ", " + j + "]");
                }*/

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have it setup like:

- keyletter = "a"
- keyletter2 = "b"
- etc.

[Loop problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm6tS.png)

Comment: What the type of keyletter, keyletter2 and what is the type of crossword array?

Comment: I believe everything is a string. I wrote: string keyletter = "g"; and string[,] crossword = new string[,] {etc.};

Comment: Is the full code much longer than this? I would debug it if I could have the full code.

Comment: I will edit my comment and put the full code in. I've added a bit more

Comment: Basically I just want to say, ok keyLetter2 is at [x,y], without it going off into an infinite spiral lol. Also the problem line is commented out, it's the i--;

Comment: `if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i-1, j])` you are going to have `IndexOutOfRangeException` thrown if `i == 0`; same issue with `else if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i+1, j])` when `i == crossword.GetLength(0) - 1`

Comment: I'm going to add a buffer so every first i is like z or something and every first j is z that way it has something to compare, but wont mess up my scan. That will be when I create the full 20x20 array though.

Comment: I run the code, but it is not infinite loop for me.

Comment: I have added a picture to show what it happening for me.

Comment: Please could you reduce your code to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem? At the moment there's a lot of commented out code and rather more blank lines than required, making it harder to read the code than it needs to be.

Comment: i--; is the problem @Jon Skeet. Koviroli asked for the whole thing.

Comment: There's a big difference between "post a complete example" and "post code with a lot of commented out code that makes it hard to read". When asking a question, it's best to consider what readers will find useful. It's *very* useful to have complete code that reproduces the problem, so that readers can run it for themselves. It's *not* useful to have a lot of code that's irrelevant to the problem. When writing a question, take some time to slim down the code to just what's required to demonstrate the issue. Often you'll find the problem yourself while doing that.

Comment: (It's also preferable to use a consistent formatting style  - this currently has a mixture of 2-space indents and 4-space indents, brace-at-end-of-line and brace-on-separate-line. Ideally, format in the common C# style of brace-on-separate-line, 4 space indents. If you're using Visual Studio, just asking it to reformat the whole document will do that for you.)

Comment: I did not read the whole code as I can't tell what's relevant, but if you are really getting an infinite loop, and your loop is incrementing `i` in the for loop, and you're decrmenting `i` in the loop body (`i--`), then that would create an infinite loop. For example: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Console.WriteLine("i == " + i); i--; }`

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with the statement

//if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i-1, j])

Here, if the matrix is like

"

a b c

d e f

g h i

"

and suppose you want to search for pattern "ba", Then obviously you will look for b, hence i will be 0 and j will be 1. Now, you are going to do (i-1) which will be -1(there are no negative indexes), Hence the error.

The best approach to do this is to check if i or j are already 0 or not. If they are 0, then you don't need a i-1 or j-1 and you can go like
" if(i!=0) 
then
if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i-1, j])
...
"

Comment: Furthermore, check for extreme conditions too, like if j is max, i is max or j is min or i is min

Comment: Ok, however in my code I'm searching for g. Which is purposely in the middle of everything [1,2]. Then I look for c, which is not >0 because g was in the middle. Don't worry about the -1 thing. When I create the full array I will add buffer indexes. The point is im trying to get i = 1 to i =0. All I want to do is say - keyword2 is at [x,y] That's it!!!!!!

Comment: It's 2am and I'm literally just doing this so I dont have to do this dumb spanish crossword. Thought it would be fun and it was, but I need to go to sleep soon!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any *infinite loop*, but run time exceptions (`IndexOutOfRangeException`) at

```
if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i-1, j]) {...}      // if i == 0
...
else if (keyLetter2 == crossword[i+1, j]) {...} // if i == crossword.GetLength(0) - 1
```

Let's get rid of these exceptions and brush up the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < crossword.GetLength(0); ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < crossword.GetLength(1); ++j)
    if (keyLetter == crossword[i, j]) {
      // Keep you messages being readable with a help of string interpolation - $""
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        $"{keyLetter} is [{i}, {j}]",
         ""
        $"i is: {i}",
         "" 
        $"j is: {j}",
         ""
      ));

      // Do not repeat yourself: if you want 4 neighbors to test
      for (int neighbor = 0; neighbor < 4; ++neighbor) {
        int ii = i + (neighbor % 2) * (neighbor - 1);
        int jj = j + (1 - neighbor % 2) * (neighbor - 1);

        // Check indexes ii, jj before addressing [ii, jj]
        if (ii >= 0 && ii < crossword.GetLength(0) &&
            jj >= 0 && jj < crossword.GetLength(1) && 
            keyLetter2 == crossword[ii, jj]) {
          Console.Write($"[i/j] position for {keyLetter2} is [{i}, {j}]");

          // In case we want at most one neighbor; comment it out if we want all of them
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

In case you have `8` (not `4`) neighbors to check

```
    ...
    bool found = false;

    for (int ii = Math.Max(0, i - 1); ii <= Math.Min(i + 1, crossword.GetLength(0)) && !found; ++ii) 
      for (int jj = Math.Max(0, j - 1); jj <= Math.Min(j + 1, crossword.GetLength(0)) && !found; ++jj) {
        if ((ii != i || jj != j) && keyLetter2 == crossword[ii, jj])) {
          Console.Write($"[i/j] position for {keyLetter2} is [{i}, {j}]");

          // In case we want at most one neighbor; comment it out if we want all of them 
          found = true;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach, which would be to delegate the "neighbor search" to a helper method. You can pass to this method the array, the cell whose neighbors should be searched, and the value that you're searching for.

Because a cell item is defined by two integer coordinates, and because there's an existing `Point` structure we can use that has two integer properties (`X` and `Y`), I'm using that to represent a cell in our array.

The helper function works by determining the minimum value of `X` and `Y` around the cell whose neighbors we're searching by subtracting `1` from it's `X` and `Y` values. Then we need to make sure this result is not less than `0` to ensure we stay within the bounds of the array.

Likewise, we add `1` to get the maximum value, and make sure it's not greater than the upper bound of the array.

Finally, we return the list of matches (if any were found) in a `List<Point>`:

```
public static List<Point> GetNeighborMatches(string[,] grid, Point item, string valueToFind)
{
    var result = new List<Point>();

    // if our grid is empty or the item isn't in it, return an empty list
    if (grid == null || grid.Length == 0 ||
        item.X < 0 || item.X > grid.GetUpperBound(0) ||
        item.Y < 0 || item.Y > grid.GetUpperBound(1))
    {
        return result;
    }

    // Get min and max values of x and y for searching
    var minX = Math.Max(item.X - 1, 0);
    var maxX = Math.Min(item.X + 1, grid.GetUpperBound(0));
    var minY = Math.Max(item.Y - 1, 0);
    var maxY = Math.Min(item.Y + 1, grid.GetUpperBound(1));

    // Loop through all neighbors to find a match
    for (int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++)
        {
            // Continue looping if we're on the 'item'
            if (x == item.X && y == item.Y) continue;

            // If this is a match, add it to our list
            if (grid[x, y] == valueToFind) result.Add(new Point(x, y));
        }
    }

    // Return all the matching neighbors
    return result;
}
```

Now we can use this helper method inside your existing code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string keyLetter = "g";
    string keyLetter2 = "b";
    string[,] crossword = new string[,]
    {
        { "a", "b", "c", "d" },
        { "e", "f", "g", "h" },
        { "a", "e", "b", "c" },
        { "i", "j", "k", "l" }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < crossword.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < crossword.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (keyLetter == crossword[i, j])
            {
                // we found a match for our first letter!
                Console.WriteLine("The first value (" + keyLetter + ") is at [" + 
                    i + ", " + j + "]");

                // get neighboring matches for keyLetter2
                List<Point> matches = GetNeighborMatches(crossword, 
                    new Point(i, j), keyLetter2);

                // Output our matches if we found any
                if (matches.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var match in matches)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The second value (" + keyLetter2 + 
                            ") is at [" + match.X + ", " + match.Y + "]");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No match was found for '" + keyLetter2 + 
                        "' near [" + i + ", " + j + "]");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]